# Proxmox Guest: Network Device not linked

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface, devices, proxmox

I've setup a new Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine using Proxmox. On this new virtual machine I can't get a working Internet connection. The command `lshw -C network` shows:

```
root@web:~# lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 12
       bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
       logical name: ens18
       version: 20
       serial: 7e:03:e4:16:f7:72
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139cp driverversion=1.3 duplex=full latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:11 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:c0040000-c00400ff memory:c0000000-c003ffff
```

The network device isn't linked. I dis/enabled the network device a few times using Proxmox, I restarted the machine many times, I tried all the different models of network devices, and I checked if my CPU supports virtualization (it does).

Comment: Can you `ping` the host system?

Comment: Do you have other virtual machines in the same Proxmox node that have working network devices?

Comment: I'm wondering if your Promox installation is configured correctly; you need to have a bridge defined in Promox, and your virtual machine's network interface(s) need to be configured to use that bridge. Alternatively you can use NAT mode.